# Filtering and multiplying filtered matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, filter, multiplication

I'd like to filter my matrix according to a specified criteria, then doing multiplication on filtered matrix and then joining multiplied filtered matrix with remainder part of matrix. E.g. I've matrix a as follows:

```
 a =
 1     2     3     4
 4     5     6     2
```

then, i'm going to filter it based on the second row to do multiplication on them: The column items which have the value <=4 are chosen for multiplication by exp(-0.5). then I'd like to have the total initial matrix by the new row assigned to filtered column. i.e. desired output is:

```
a =
 1     2     3     4
 2.4261     5     6     1.2131
```

For this I tried `b= a(2,:)<=4` to have the filtered matrix and used `bsxfun(@times,a(2,b),exp(-0.5))`for multiplication, then should I have another matrix `c= a(2,:)>4` for the remaining unfiltered columns and then joining them? Any help for a better implementation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
%// you have done this
mask = a(2,:)<=4;

%// taking 2nd row and masked cols and doing operations on those elements alone
a(2,mask) = a(2,mask).*exp(-0.5);
```

**Results:**

**Input:**

```
a =

 1     2     3     4
 4     5     6     2
```

**Output:**

```
>> a

a =

1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000
2.4261    5.0000    6.0000    1.2131
```

Comment: Just If I do it for several cell items (each cell row contains a matrix as my example), can the whole solution be considered as a function and use cellfun for it? currently i use for loop and your solution in the loop. And also how much really differs using cellfun instead of for?

Comment: @hamideh you could do with `cellfun`. Use `tic.. toc` to see which one is faster

Comment: Thanks for your directions